# Slickgrid spreadsheet plugin clear all filters

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid with this filtering plugin:

https://github.com/danny-sg/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins/blob/master/ext.headerfilter.js

This is the clear method for each column:

```
        $('<button>Clear</button>')
            .appendTo($menu)
            .bind('click', function (ec) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(columnDef));
                // console.log($menuButton.data("column"));
                // alert($menuButton.data("column").id);
                columnDef.filterValues.length = 0;
                setButtonImage($menuButton, false);
                handleApply(ec, columnDef);
            });
```

I want to make a button on the page that clears all filters and resets the button images. I've got this far but am stuck:

```
$("#clearallfilters, #clearallfilters-sm").click(function () {
  for (var filcolumn in grid.getColumns()) {
    filcolumn.filterValues.length = 0;
    //then change all pictures
  }
})
```

I assume I need to loop through the columns and 0 out the filterValues but don't for the life of me know how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it like this you need to reset the column because thats where filervalues are stored

```
var clearcolumns = grid.getColumns();
for (var i = 0; i < clearcolumns.length; i++) {
if (clearcolumns[i].filterValues !== undefined) {
    delete clearcolumns[i].filterValues;
}
}
grid.setColumns(clearcolumns);
dataView.refresh();
grid.render();enter code here
```

Comment: Very neat thanks Michael. It changes the filter icon back to the default arrow too, which is great.